# sklearn Features don't affect accuracy

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I have recently divided into machine learning using sklearn. After using it with some data I have noticed that no matter if I remove or add features the accuracy didn't change (it is stuck at, 0.66668208448967). in other words

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


scores = []
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/fozoro/Downloads/test.csv')

X = data[["x","y"]]
y = data[["correct"]]

knn = LogisticRegression()
knn.fit(X,y.values.ravel())

scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, y.values.ravel(), cv = 10, scoring = "accuracy")

print(scores.mean())
```

This code prints `0.66668208448967`

to better illustrate my point I have added a column to my CSV file which is entirely made out of 0 (I named the column `zeros`). after changing 
 `X = data[["x","y"]]` to  `X = data[["zeros"]]` I end up with this code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


scores = []
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/fozoro/Downloads/HQ_Questions_Rest_new_test.csv')

X = data[["zeros"]]
y = data[["correct"]]

knn = LogisticRegression()
knn.fit(X,y.values.ravel())

scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, y.values.ravel(), cv = 10, scoring = "accuracy")

print(scores.mean())
```

and it still prints out the same score of `0.66668208448967`.

At this point, I'm assuming that it is still using the over two columns `x` and `y` though I fail to understand why. Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

This is a small part of the csv file.

```
0   44600  yes
12  41700  no
574 14500  no
```

When I print(data.dtypes) I get the following:

```
Q + ans                    int64
Q + ans broken search      int64
Bing total Search          int64
mean1                    float64
mean2                    float64
zeros                      int64
correct                    int64
dtype: object
```

When I print(data.describe()) I get the following:

```
          Q + ans  Q + ans broken search  Bing total Search       mean1  \
count  477.000000             477.000000       4.770000e+02  477.000000   
mean     3.972746              30.408805       3.661450e+06    3.972746   
std     12.112970             133.128478       1.555090e+07    7.292793   
min      0.000000               0.000000       0.000000e+00    0.000000   
25%      0.000000               0.000000       8.110000e+04    0.000000   
50%      0.000000               0.000000       3.790000e+05    1.333333   
75%      2.000000               4.000000       2.000000e+06    5.333333   
max    162.000000            1908.000000       2.320000e+08   60.666667   

                mean2  zeros     correct  
    count  477.000000  477.0  477.000000  
    mean    30.272537    0.0    0.333333  
    std     76.365587    0.0    0.471899  
    min      0.000000    0.0    0.000000  
    25%      0.000000    0.0    0.000000  
    50%      1.666667    0.0    0.000000  
    75%     21.000000    0.0    1.000000  
    max    636.666667    0.0    1.000000
```

Comment: How is your target value y distributed? I would guess that 2/3 of your data belongs to one class and 1/3 to other classes. Also, you dont have to fit your estimator before you pass it to `cross_val_score`, see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

Comment: Can you try to provide a [mcve]? Also add the code where you changed `X` and refit the model.

Comment: @Merlin1896 are you talking about the length of the columns? (they all have the same amount of data)

Comment: @Fozoro No, I am not talking about column lengths. I am talking about the distribution of your y values ("correct" column). I would expect them to to be integer numbers and each integer represents one class. So how are you "correct" values (your classes) distributed? How many classes are there?

Comment: @pault I just added the problematic code. do you want me to include the csv file?

Comment: The logit function is of the form `exp(-(B0 + B1X1 + ... BNXN))` where the `B`s are the fitted coefficients and the `X`s are the data. In the case where you are only using one feature (constant 0), this reduces to `exp(-B0)` - thus you will get the same prediction for each observation. Is it possible that `B1X1 + B2Y = 0`? Try printing out the coefficients to check.

Comment: You dont have to provide the full file, but some rows from both files would be helpful.

Comment: @Merlin1896 Oh my bad the correct column is made out of yes and no so it only contains string

Comment: @paul what I don't understand how come I get the same result when I have add 4 features than when I have 1 feature. when I type `knn.coef_` I get [[0.]]

Comment: @Merlin1896 I added a part of the csv

Comment: @Fozoro that means there is one coefficient (which is 0). What is the output of `knn.coeff_` when you use the 4 features? Also check out the intercepts.

Comment: @pault when I use all the columns I get [[-1.16326857e-09 -1.53825197e-08 -2.72650907e-08 -8.70778534e-10]] as `knn.coef_` and the same score of 0.66668208448967

Comment: @Fozoro Those coefficients are all essentially 0. This means that your model is not fitting well. Can you print data.dtypes? Also do `data.describe()` to see the stats for your columns.

Comment: I added the results of data.dtypes to the question ( it was too long to added it as a comment )

Comment: @pault I'm very sorry I didn't see that you wanted me to also type `data.describe()` I just added it to the question too

Comment: @Fozoro it's hard to tell without digging into your data, but it seems like your model is not very good. Try taking a look at pairwise histogram plots to see what if any relationship exists between your features and the target. You may need to do some feature engineering or scaling first. Or you may want to try a non-linear model (like RandomForest).

Comment: @pault Yeah I will try to do so. thanks for the help though:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your "correct" column. You provide strings ("yes" and "no") where numbers are expected.

For example, substitute all "yes" with 1 and all "no" with 0 and then try again.

See the following minimal example:

test.csv:

```
x,y,correct,zeros
1,1,1.0,0
2,2,0.0, 0
1,2,0.0,0
3,1,1.0,0
3,1,1.0,0
4,2,0.0, 0
5,2,0.0,0
6,1,1.0,0
7,1,1.0,0
8,2,0.0, 0
9,2,0.0,0
10,1,1.0,0
11,1,1.0,0
12,1,1.0,0
13,1,1.0,0
14,1,1.0,0
15,1,1.0,0
16,1,1.0,0
```

Content of the python file:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
data = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")
X = data[["x","y"]]
y = data[["correct"]]
knn = LogisticRegression()
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, y.values.ravel(), cv=3, scoring="accuracy")
scores.mean()
```

Try to replace the line 
`X = data[["x","y"]]` with `X = data[["zeros"]]` and notice the difference!

From the statistics of your data we can learn that 318 of the 477 samples in your data set belong to the 0 (or "no") group. These are 2/3 or `0.666...`
So if your model cannot learn anything from the provided features, it will always output a zero (since all coefficients are zero). Hence, for any input, the predicted class will be 0 (or "no"). This is why you get always the same score: The model always predicts a 0 and 2/3 of your data belong to the zero class, so your model is in 66% of the cases right.

With my provided data samples you see that it DOES make a difference, if we use the "x" and "y" column or the "zeros" column. In the first case, we get a score of over 72%. If we just use the meaningless "zeros", we get 66%, because of the class distribution of our data set.

Comment: I tried replacing yes with 1 and no with 0 but it still yield the same result

Comment: Scikit automatically converts string targets to numerical, so no need to do that explicitly. The second part of answer is good.

Comment: @VivekKumar You are right! I retried it with "yes" and "no" instead of 1 and 0 and got the same result. Thanks for pointing that out.